# How to scrape using file_get_contents(url) without replacing links

Tags: php, web-scraping

noob here..

So i am experimenting with scraping using `file_get_contents($url)`, however the returned content has all its links modified (domain name removed and many weird characters added in case of anchor hrefs and image srcs)

```
<?php

    $url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=foo+bar';

    $file = file_get_contents($url);
    echo($file);
```

An example of anchor link returned from above:

```
<a class="result__url" href="/l/?kh=-1&amp;uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFoobar">
              en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar
              </a>
```

Actual anchor link when i enter the url manually on browser:

```
<a class="result__url" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar">
                  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar
                  </a>
```

This happens with every site i try. What is causing this ? And How can i get the content AS IT IS. Please throw some light.

Side question: Is there any better way to scrape duckduckgo results ? I see they don't have a public search api (the one available is only a answers api that doesn't work for search)

Comment: good day dear Subrata - well i like your approach - it looks pretty elaborated. Thanks for sharing with us your ideas and the code!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my idea, after we **scrape** through `file_get_contents()`.

1. remove the encoded text **/l/?kh=-1&uddg=** then
2. extract all link common links put at href, right ? so in this case I did it with `preg_match_all` (reference : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)
   here is the [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern : **~href="([^"]+)"(.*?)>~**
3. loop the links that we have extracted and replace decode the url (because duckduckgo encode the url)

here is my sample code :

```
<?php

    $url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=foo+bar';

    $file = file_get_contents($url);
    $file = str_replace("/l/?kh=-1&amp;uddg=", "", $file);

    preg_match_all('~href="([^"]+)"(.*?)>~', $file, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $link) 
    {
        $file = str_replace($link, urldecode($link), $file);
    }

    var_dump ($file);
    die();
```

FYI. DuckDuckGo also provided search API http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=Google&format=json , but you said just for experiment but it's ok

Hope it helps !

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, and about the search api, it returns no search results in json format (when format=json is given), but returns normally when i remove &format=json. So, after searching a while, found that its only a answers api, not search, am i correct? or there's any hope to get it work?